# Creating simple button for .mp3 file download (no right-click, no media player)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure this is a simple task, but on my wordpress site I want to create a download button that forces an .mp3 download, without opening a player (when left clicked), or the user having to right-click 'save target as'. I just need a straight forward button, that when left-clicked causes a file to be downloaded (as well as being easily trackable by Google Analytics).

Is a .php script required for this? You'd think this would be a very common function, and easy to solve....but I have spent hours on this and have been unable to get anything to work.

*if it's not obvious my coding skills are nearly non-existent.

I really appreciate anybody's time who can help me figure this out. Thanks!

***EDIT

Just found this on another post, but no comments if it would work or not. It was for a .pdf file though...

```
<?php   
if (isset($_GET['file'])) { 
    $file = $_GET['file'] ;
        if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.pdf$/',$file))  { 
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');  
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");   
            readfile($file); 
        } 
    } else { 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
    echo "<h1>Error 404: File Not Found: <br /><em>$file</em></h1>"; 
} 
?>
```

Save the above as download.php

Save this little snippet as a PHP file somewhere on your server and you can use it to make a file download in the browser, rather than display directly. If you want to serve files other than PDF, remove or edit line 5.

You can use it like so:

Add the following link to your HTML file.

```
<a href="download.php?file=my_pdf_file.pdf">Download the cool PDF.</a>
```

Comment: You cannot force the browser to do anything. That software does not belong to you.

Comment: @EdHeal - my understanding is you can force the header for the request to an octect stream which tells the browser not treat it as a file, not as say a MIME type of video or audio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is possible, but you need to write a script to do it. This is a pretty poor (security and basic coding wise) from http://youngdigitalgroup.com.au/tutorial-force-download-mp3-file-streaming/

```
file: downloadit.php

<?php
header ("Content-type: octet/stream"); 
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";"); 
header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 
readfile($file); 
exit;
?>
```

you would then place it into a publicly accessible folder and build your links as such:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/downloadit.php?file=/uploads/dir/file.mp3
```

what this does is tells the browser to treat the file as a stream of bytes, rather than a particular MIME type which the browser would ordinarily do based on the file extension.

Comment: Trent thanks for that. When you say poor for security and coding reasons...what should i be worried about if I used it? I'm not concerned about the file being stolen or anything, but does it open my site up to being hacked or something?

Comment: well, if they did /wp-config.php you'd be in trouble :) You may wish to use a database to manage an acceptable file list, or in the script validate that the only files they can download are .mp3

Comment: also, this solution is rather serverload heavy as your script is actually opening the file and streaming it back

Comment: heavier than if the user right-clicked > 'save target as'?